# Why do I get Access Denied when starting WSL?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I think I made a booboo this morning, I clicked "Install updates and shutdown" when my battery was too low, and then it shut down right after the boot loader screen (before the blue "working X %" screen showed).

And now `wsl` just says "Access Denied" if I try to run it from an elevated PS prompt. I suspect there is a connection.

I have looked at all sorts of answers from 3 years ago, but they don't really fit my situation. I have also looked in `C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState` where there's supposed to be an `ext4.vhdx` file, at least for `wsl 2`, but I only see folders `rootfs` and `temp`. This distribution is running version 1, though.

I am relatively clueless about methods to debug why `wls` errors out -- does it even start, or does the error come from PS?

How do I correct the problem?

P.S. The rest of Windows 10 seems to be working normally. Windows update tells me that I'm up to date, and the last time it installed anything was KB5001716 on 2023-10-13.

Comment: At least I found where the files are so I can back them up somewhere and reinstall WSL. But I'm lazy.

Comment: If edxt4.vhdx is missing then have left your WSL instance.  You will have to reinstall whichever distribution you had installed.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks. I was not sure whether WSL 1 actually used a VHD, it it's not actually a virtual machine.

Comment: Why are you running WSL from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @Ramhound: Ignorance, probably, or just to see if it made a difference. I tried a lot of things. Also I had the PC freeze yesterday and after a hard power cycle, WSL worked again(!) The only difference that I can see is a zero length `IO_REPARSE_TAG_AF_UNIX` reparse point named `fsserver` in the same folder as above. No `ext4.vhdx`, version 1 doesn't seem to use that.

Comment: because its Microsoft, bro. they themselves don’t know how to solve problems with their software